# How can I raise the level of an existing paved patio?

Tags: patio

We recently had our back garden paved but the level is lower than I would like it to have been, leaving a big step from the kitchen door to the patio.

Is it feasible to pave over the slabs, or even to reuse them over a raised floor?

Comment: How many inches to you want to raise it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably add another layer of pavers right over that old patio, it can support the weight. The other option would be to removed all the slabs, then add and compact down an inch or two layer of stone dust to raise the area.